# SignalR Invoke only after successful connection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, .net-core, signalr

I'm working on an angular spa. I'm kinda new to angular, typescript and web development in general, so bear with me.

The webpage contains a list of "jobs". The user can open the details to a job, adjust parameters and tell the server to execute this job. When a user opens the job, lets call it job-detail-component, SignalR is used to send updates on the details of this job. This happens via an invoke command in ngOnInit in the job-detail-component.

**app-component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.SignalRService.startConnection();
}
```

**job-detail-component:**

```
job: IJob;

ngOnInit() {    
    var jobId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('jobId');
    this.SignalRService.hubConnection.on('jobstate', (data: any) => {
      console.log("received job state");
      this.job = data;
    });
    this.SignalRService.subscribeJob(jobId);
```

**SignalR-service**

```
public async startConnection() {
  this.hubConnection.start()
    .then(() => {
       console.log("Connected to server");
      })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log('Error while starting connection: ');
       console.log(err);
    }
  )
}

public subscribeJob(jobId: string) {
  console.log("subscribing to job");
  this.hubConnection.invoke("SubJobState", jobId);
}
```

Now the part above works great until someone enters the job directly via a direct link to the job, say `http://localhost:5000/job-detail/1`. Now they have entered the detail page for job number 1, `hubconnection.start()` is executed by `app.component.ts`, `hubconnection.invoke()` is executed from job detail component, and the following error is thrown:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot send data if the 
connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

This must happen due to `SignalRService.startConnection()` is currently working on connecting to the hub, and invoke is called before the connection is created.

I solved the issue with what I mean is probably a non-ideal solution:

```
public subscribeJob(jobId: string) {
  if (this.hubConnection.state === 1) {
    console.log("subscribing to job");
    this.hubConnection.invoke("SubJobState", jobId);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.subscribeJob(jobId);
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve it than this method?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample code that allows you to call `invoke` at any time.

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder} from '@microsoft/signalr';
import {from, Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";
import {mergeMap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export default class SignalrService {

  private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private readonly startedConnection:Promise<any>;

  constructor() {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${window.location.href}chatHub`)
      .build();

    this.startedConnection = this.startConnection();
  }

  on(method: string): Observable<any> {

    const subject = new Subject<any>();

    this._hubConnection.on(method, data => {
      return subject.next(data);
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
  }


   invoke(method: string, ...data: any): Observable<any> {

     return from(this.startedConnection)
       .pipe(
         mergeMap(_ => {
           return this._hubConnection.invoke(method, ...data)
         })
       )

  }

  private startConnection() {
    return this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started');
        return 'connected'
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection, retrying...');
        setTimeout(this.startConnection, 5000)
      });
  }

}
```

Inject it into you component and use it as below:

```js
export class HomeComponent implements  OnDestroy{

  private  subscriptions = new Subscription();

  constructor(private signalr: SignalrService) {}

  users$ = this.signalr.on("ReceiveUsers");
  messages$ = this.signalr.on("ReceiveMessages");


  ngOnInit(): void {
    const sendUsersSub = this.signalr.invoke("SendUsers").subscribe();
    this.subscriptions.add(sendUsersSub);

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I confronted with this problem once and I solved it like this.

Imagine function A is a public function that :

1- can be called anywhere anytime.(in any component)

2- needs SingnalR connection to be created.

```
    public A() {
        //some code that needs SignalR connection to be created
    }
```

By developing the project you will add some other functions that are like function A.

```
     public B() {
         // like function A , it needs SignalR connection to be created
      }
```

Instead of calling these two functions anywhere anytime, call a manager function which is public and receive a value (can be as enum) that tells us which previous functions should be called. in addition make A and B private.

```
    private A() {
        //some code that needs SignalR connection to be created
    }

    private B() {
         // like function A , it needs SignalR connection to be created
    }

    public manager(type:string) {
        if (type === 'A') this.A();
        else if (type === 'B') this.B();
    }
```

so why add manager function? because you can hook it to a boolean variable (lets call it connected) which control the state of connection. if the connection is true so run it . if the connection is not true you can add it to a queue.
for the sake of single responsibility I just check the connection state in manager function and other duties hand over to other two other functions.

```
    public manager(type:string) {
        if (this.connected === true) this.callProperFunction(type)
        else this.addToQueue(type)
    }
    private callProperFunction(type:string) {
        if (type === 'A') this.A();
        else if (type === 'B') this.B();
    }
    private addToQueue(type:string) {
        this.queue.push(type);
        // you can implement a queue with simple array.
        // just add to end (push) and read from front (shift)
    }
```

finally the last part is about your varibale (connected: boolean) which must listen to the state of the signalR. you can easily implement it with Angular Observable.

```
    this.connection.subscribe((state:boolean) => {
          //first change the state for future calling
        this.connected = state; 
          //run all the functions which was store in queue.
        for (let i=0; i<this.queue.length; i++) {
          //call from the front
          const type = this.queue.shift();
          //now call all the methods  which was blocked when the state                          
          // was false and not connected 
          this.callProperFunction(type);
        }
    }
```

final note: You must tell all the subscribers whenever the signalR connection is created!

```
private startConnection() {
    return this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started');
        **this.someSharedService.changeConnectionState(true);**
        return 'connected'
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection, retrying...');
        setTimeout(this.startConnection, 5000)
      });
  }
```